# Group and take top K of each group with aggregation framwork

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with documents in that format:

```
{ "_id":..., "Group": 1, "Value": 4 }
{ "_id":..., "Group": 2, "Value": 8 }
{ "_id":..., "Group": 1, "Value": 10 }
```

and so on...

Given X, Y and K, I would like to use aggregation framework to do the following:

- Select all documents with the `Group` property between X and Y
- Group by the `Group` property
- In each group: pick only the K documents with the largest `Value` property

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 8):

The first two steps are easy enough:

```
X = 1; Y = 3
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $match: { Group: { $gte: X, $lt: Y } } },
    { $group: { _id: '$Group' } }
] );
```

With the above dataset, that gives you:

```
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : 2 }, { "_id" : 1 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

In order to be able to pick the K docs with the largest value, you need to modify your group to include each document and the max value for that group, and then we unwind so that we can sort on group and value (DESC):

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $match: { Group: { $gte: X, $lt: Y } } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$Group', 
        docs: { $push: { _id: '$_id', Group: '$Group', Value: '$Value' } }
    } },
    { $unwind: '$docs' },
    { $sort: { 'docs.Group': 1, 'docs.Value': -1 } }
] );
```

From now on, we're struck though, as unlike $push as normal query operator, we can't do a $push + $slice in the aggregation framework yet. The only thing we can do, is another group so your application can pick out the K documents per group with the highest values:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $match: { Group: { $gte: X, $lt: Y } } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$Group', 
        docs: { $push: { _id: '$_id', Group: '$Group', Value: '$Value' } }
    } },
    { $unwind: '$docs' },
    { $sort: { 'docs.Group': 1, 'docs.Value': -1 } }
    { $group: {
        _id: '$docs.Group', 
        docs: { $push: { 
            _id: '$docs._id', 
            Group: '$docs.Group', 
            Value: '$docs.Value' 
        } } 
    } }
] );
```

Which then outputs (after adding a few more documents):

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "docs" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a73dea832e98dd545f68"),
                    "Group" : 2,
                    "Value" : 22
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a738ea832e98dd545f66"),
                    "Group" : 2,
                    "Value" : 17
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a73aea832e98dd545f67"),
                    "Group" : 2,
                    "Value" : 13
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a2aaea832e98dd545f64"),
                    "Group" : 2,
                    "Value" : 8
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a736ea832e98dd545f65"),
                    "Group" : 2,
                    "Value" : 7
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "docs" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a740ea832e98dd545f69"),
                    "Group" : 1,
                    "Value" : 21
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a2a5ea832e98dd545f63"),
                    "Group" : 1,
                    "Value" : 10
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a742ea832e98dd545f6a"),
                    "Group" : 1,
                    "Value" : 5
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a2a3ea832e98dd545f62"),
                    "Group" : 1,
                    "Value" : 4
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51e3a745ea832e98dd545f6b"),
                    "Group" : 1,
                    "Value" : 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Update for MongoDB >= v3.2:**

You can now add a `$project` stage to the end of your aggregation pipeline in order limit the number of items per group:

```
$project: {
    _id: '$_id',
    docs: {
        $slice: [ 
            '$docs',
            3 // max number of elements returned from the start of the array
        ]
    } 
}
```

Comment: Good Idea. Slice does the job

Answer (score 0):

take N:

```js
db.rec_log.aggregate( [
    { $match: { uid: { $in: [ "zxf-1", "zxf-2" ] } } },
    { $sort: { uid: 1, c_date: -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$uid', docs: { $push: { content: '$content' } } } },
    { $project: { _id: '$_id', docs: { $slice: [ '$docs', 2 ] } } }
] );
```

take One:

```js
db.rec_log.aggregate( [
    { $match: { uid: { $in: [ "zxf-1", "zxf-2" ] } } },
    { $sort: { uid: 1, c_date: -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$uid', docs: { $push: { content: '$content' } } } },
    { $project: { _id: '$_id', docs0: { $arrayElemAt: ["$docs", 0] } } },
    { $project: { _id: '$_id', latest_content: "$docs0.content" } }
] );
```